# How To construct Intents in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm creating a chatbot to identify questions about store and products and answer accordingly with Dialogflow. But when constructing intents I came across this problem. The approaches I think I can construct as follows.

**1st Approach**

Create multiple intents

```
GetPrice, GetColor, GetAvailability, GetType, GetStoreName, GetStoreContact
```

The difficulty that I found in this approach is I have to create dozens of intents for all product types and for all types of questions about store

The advantage is that I can train for the intents seperately.

**2nd Approach**

Create 2 intents

```
ProductQuestions, StoreQuestions
```

The training has to be done for all the 1st approach question types in those 2

What approach I should take? In future this will be more scalable.

Answer (score 3):

Most logic for conversation design can be based on your personal preferences. If you're looking for best practices, check out Google's documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/best-practices

Answer (score 1):

As per my opinion you should go with 1st approach. It is more flexible and scalable.
You would need to make many intents for sure but you would be able to get what user wants to know exactly.

In the 2nd approach, you would need to do many things for which you are using DialogFlow.

Try making conversation flow chart before designing the intents.

Answer (score 1):

Using Dialogflow:

**WorkFlow:**

- Open the [Actions Console](https://console.actions.google.com/).
- Click on Add/import project.
- Type in a Project name, like "actions-codelab". This name is for your own internal reference; later on, you can set an external name for your project.
- Click Create Project.
- Rather than pick a category, click Skip on the upper-right corner.
- Click Build > Actions in the left nav.
- Click Add your first Action.
- Select at least one language for your Action, followed by Update. For this codelab, we recommend only selecting English.
- On the Custom intent card, click Build. This will open the Dialogflow Console in another tab.

**2. Test with Dialogflow:**

Dialogflow generates and uploads an Action package to your actions project automatically when you test it. To test your Action:

- Make sure the Web & App Activity, Device Information, and Voice & Audio Activity permissions are enabled on the [Activity controls](https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols) page for your Google account.
- Click on Integrations in the Dialogflow console's left navigation.
- Click on the Google Assistant card to bring up the integration screen and click TEST. Dialogflow uploads your Action package to Google's servers, so you can test the latest version in the simulator.
- In the Actions console simulator, enter "talk to my test app" in the Input area of the simulator to test your Action. If you have already specified an invocation name and saved your invocation information, you can start the conversation by saying talk to  instead.

**Note**: If you don't see a TEST button, you need to click on the AUTHORISE button first to give Dialogflow access to your Google account and Actions project.

For more information refer below link:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/index.html#0

Comment: @tha07 Accept answer if you got answer.